# How can i Use External Storage in android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

This is for the first time i am using external storage in android.
I need some help how can i perform different operations such as how to check whether External Storage is available or not?, How to write files or pictures into storage .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to check whether External Storage is available or not?

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageState()`.

> How to write files or pictures into storage

Use standard Java I/O, working off a directory built using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: If you write files, dont forget to set the permission in the Manifest. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: thanks a lot..
I have used this already but i want to able to add files to media storage and then retrieve it back.. So any hints?

U can even send some reference..Thanks

Comment: @rakesh-gondaliya: You ask a question, then say you "used this already". Why did you ask the question in the first place?

Comment: sorry for that.
Can u give me some hints to create app which will allow me to write files into External storage and then i will be able to read that.
thanks

Comment: @rakesh-gondaliya: Use standard Java I/O, working off a directory built using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. If you are unfamiliar with Java I/O, I suggest that you spend a month or two outside of Android learning Java.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify the first part of CommonsWare's answer (I couldn't seem to add a comment to the comment stream): you want to check that...

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
```

... is true.