# How to find the default storage location in android to store any file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sqlite

I want to download a file and want to store it in some default location like internal storage or in the External storage.
So I am stuck how to get that default storage?

Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check if the external storage is available this link will help you :

[how to check internal and external storage if exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616974/how-to-check-internal-and-external-storage-if-exist)

Second you create a folder or use a folder to save to it :)

This link will help you :)

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks For Answering my Question, 
But Still I have Doubt that If We have space in both External storage as well as in the Internal storage. But somebody has chosen from Setting that any file should store in the External Directory or It should store in the internal Directory. Then will it work.