# Is there a way to determine if Android storage device is internal or external?

Tags: android, android-ndk, mount, fuse

As title says, based on path, is there a way to reliable distinguish if the storage is internal or external (SD Card, HDD via USB)?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check internal and external storage if exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616974/how-to-check-internal-and-external-storage-if-exist)

Comment: is this sufficent for you? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#isExternalStorageRemovable(java.io.File)

Comment: The question is wrong. What you seem to want is to distinguish between removable and not removable memory. Internal and external is both not removable.

Comment: Thanks for all hints, Kuffs info on isExternalStorageRemovable() works the best for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()
```

Comment: That method doesn't consider the file path though.. As of API level 21 you can use this method instead:

boolean isExternalStorageRemovable (File path)