# Environment.getExternalStorageState() returns "Removed" causing NPE in JellyBean/Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android

I am trying to create a new file using `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` but it is returning null. When I run Environment.getExternalStorageState() it is currently returning removed. This is currently only the case for Ice Cream Sandwich and Jelly Bean, as I have tested both Marshmallow and Nougat and it works fine. I am using an Emulator, how would I fix this?

Edit: I have also included read and write permissions in the Manifest. (read and write external storage)

Comment: try adding permissions to read and write external storage.

Comment: I have already defined permissions in the Manifest, (read and write external storage)

Answer (score 0):

Do you add these permissions to manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: He would receive runtime crash on Marshmallow if he had not specified.

Comment: She*, but yes, I have those permissions.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs of `getExternalFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)):

> May return **null** if shared storage is not currently available.

Which means, you have to [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7617122/1083957) weather storage is mounter or no via [`getExternalStorageState(File)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState(java.io.File)).

> Shared storage may not always be available, since removable media can be ejected by the user. Media state can be checked using **getExternalStorageState(File)**.

Comment: Yes I have already checked for getExternalStorageState(File) which evaluated to removed.